# PuPHPet VM Not Executing php

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, bolt-cms

I'm trying to get a PuPHPet VM setup to install and run Bolt CMS, but I can't get the PHP to execute. Instead, it returns the text content of the `index.php` file and does not run Bolt. My web server is nginx and the config files are as follows. Most of the settings are the default from PuPHPet. Not sure if this is related, but when I leave the `default_type  application/octet-stream;` directive, my browser downloads files instead of serving them for viewing in the browser. I've fixed this by changing that directive to `default_type  text/html;`, but I'm not sure if I should leave it that way or not.

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 1024;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
    }

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  sendfile    on;

  server_tokens on;

  types_hash_max_size 1024;
  types_hash_bucket_size 512;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
  server_names_hash_max_size 512;

  keepalive_timeout  65;
  tcp_nodelay        on;

  gzip         on;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

awesome.dev.conf

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           awesome.dev www.awesome.dev;
  client_max_body_size 1m;

  root /var/www/awesome/public;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/nxv_z49y6jkcgd4r.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/nxv_z49y6jkcgd4r.error.log;
  location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {


    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    root  /var/www/awesome/web/public;
    fastcgi_index app_dev.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;

  }
  location / {


    root  /var/www/awesome/web/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args /app.php$is_args$args;
     autoindex on;
    index  index.html index.php app.php;


  }
  location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {


    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    root  /var/www/awesome/web/public;
    fastcgi_index app.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;

  }
  location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {


    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    root  /var/www/awesome/web/public;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

  }
  sendfile off;
}
```

----EDIT
here is my `config.yml` file for my puphpet VM

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64
                box_url: 'false'
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    vflm_rqqd5ugidehp:
                        id: ajschmidtbolt
                        hostname: ajschmidtBolt
                        network:
                            private_network: 192.168.56.107
                            forwarded_port:
                                vflmnfp_6qmghncouudg:
                                    host: '8435'
                                    guest: '22'
                        memory: '512'
                        cpus: '1'
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
                module_path:
                    - puphpet/puppet/modules
                    - puphpet/puppet/manifests
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_qn3gvsa5qa7q:
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
                source: ./
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
        post_up_message: ''
    ssh:
        host: 'false'
        port: 'false'
        private_key_path: 'false'
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: 'false'
        keep_alive: '1'
        forward_agent: 'false'
        forward_x11: 'false'
        shell: 'bash -l'
        insert_key: 'false'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
    proxy:
        http: ''
        https: ''
        ftp: ''
        no_proxy: ''
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - vim
        - htop
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: en_US.UTF-8
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
        timezone: UTC
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
resolv:
    install: '1'
    nameservers:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
    domainname: ''
    searchpath: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: present
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
        proxy_send_timeout: 600s
        proxy_read_timeout: 600s
        names_hash_bucket_size: 128
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_z49y6jkcgd4r:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            locations:
                nxvl_36f73vxgmi75:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome/web
                    location: /
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    index_files:
                        - index.html
                        - index.php
                        - app.php
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                        - /app.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
                nxvl_bls2yuh6byxw:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome/web
                    location: '~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$)'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /app_dev.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: app_dev.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
                nxvl_srtr8jpu67yt:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome/web
                    location: '~ ^/index\.php(/|$)'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
                nxvl_1zmve3240rrs:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome/web
                    location: '~ ^/app\.php(/|$)'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /app.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: app.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
                        - 'APP_ENV prod'
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 2.4
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_iqnewm56uts7:
            servername: awesome.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            docroot: /var/www/awesome/web
            port: '80'
            setenvif:
                - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_key: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_chain: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_certs_dir: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_80v3pp1fpf0r:
                    path: /var/www/awesome/web
                    directoryindex: 'index.php app.dev'
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    provider: directory
            files_match:
                avfm_2kmomwazs6bp:
                    path: (app_dev|config)\.php$
                    sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                    setenv:
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    provider: filesmatch
                avfm_dtzkvhvgw5hy:
                    path: app\.php$
                    sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                    setenv:
                        - 'APP_ENV prod'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    provider: filesmatch
                avfm_5w9nbgjtc7ct:
                    path: \.php$
                    sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    provider: filesmatch
letsencrypt:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        email: ''
        webserver_service: ''
    domains: {  }
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '7.1'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - xml
            - pdo
            - mysqlnd
            - curl
            - gd
            - json
            - mbstring
            - opcache
            - posix
            - fileinfo
            - exif
            - zip
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_09o577ebb23q:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v1.1.0
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 8.0.5
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        rv_vlnpliyd6cks:
            default: '1'
            bundler: '1'
            version: 2.3.1
            gems:
                - deep_merge@1.0.1
                - activesupport@4.2.6
                - vine@0.2
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '6'
    npm_packages: {  }
mariadb:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '10.1'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    users:
        mariadbnu_3v6smbjtiwhp:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mariadbnd_itojhyi8txd8:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mariadbng_t4pwwazfj8zp:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
mysql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '5.7'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    users:
        mysqlnu_9vh72eome5im:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mysqlnd_zoondkmszl90:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_n1rmvm6lmldn:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.6'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    globals:
        version: 2.6.0
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    databases: {  }
mailhog:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '8025'
        path: /usr/local/bin/mailhog
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 2.3.1
        java_install: true
    instances:
        esi_bqomcxcoisll:
            name: es-01
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 5.5.2
        port: '8984'
```

Comment: The default puphpet nginx settings work great for Symfony2 - they _should_ work fine for Bolt CMS, though.

Show us y our config.yaml, and then tell how us how you're accessing your VM - is it through the IP address or through awesome.dev?

Comment: Juan, thanks for the reply. just posted my config.yml file above.i am accessing the VM through awesome.dev

Comment: specify a default locaton for php-files `location ~ \.php$` since you may get an index.php/app.php of another directory level internally.

Comment: also this `try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;` in the `location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$)` looks loopable in case of non-existent /app.php. I see the same issue with other locations.